# Can't add a rabbitmq user in Docker file

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I try to add a rabbitmq user when I run a docker container from my image but it complains that node is down:

```
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@3af546685019: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@3af546685019]

rabbit@3af546685019:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on 3af546685019
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on 3af546685019
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-55@3af546685019'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: pgr3C5mfbuw86BKnW7cJpw==

Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@3af546685019: nodedown
```

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.6.14

ADD rabbitmq_users.sh /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin
WORKDIR /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_management
ENTRYPOINT ["rabbitmq_users.sh"]

EXPOSE 4369 25672 5672 15672
```

and rabbitmq_users.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Creating a user..."
sleep 10
rabbitmqctl add_user rmquser rmquser 2>/dev/null
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags rmquser administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / rmquser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

looks like it executes rabbitmq_users.sh first before running rabbitmq-server from the rabbitmq:3.6.14 image I inherit from because I can't see any logs proving that rabbitmq server is started up. For example if I don't create users disabling this ENTRYPOINT script, the server starts up and it works fine.

Can somebody help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work by adjusting my rabbitmq_users.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create Rabbitmq user
(rabbitmqctl add_user rmquser rmquser 2>/dev/null ; \
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags rmquser administrator ; \
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / rmquser  ".*" ".*" ".*" ; \
echo "User 'rmquser' has been created") & rabbitmq-server
```

and used CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT where I provided my script:

```
...
CMD ["rabbitmq_users.sh"]
```

Answer (score -1):

The [rabbitmq image](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/28001b529f28ed0d8e8297f8b603a4cc93a846a3/3.6/debian/Dockerfile) already has an Entrypoint defined as `ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]`. When you define your entrypoint, you are overriding the one defined in the base image. Thus rabbitmq won't start.
What you need to do is "append" your users script:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.6.14

ADD rabbitmq_users.sh /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin
WORKDIR /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_management
ENTRYPOINT ["./usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh rabbitmq-server && ./rabbitmq_users.sh"]

EXPOSE 4369 25672 5672 15672
```

Comment: this is what I receive when I run the container: "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:295: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-entrypoint.sh rabbitmq-server && rabbitmq_users.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown"

Comment: same error. I think it tries to run the scripts from ENTRYPOINT first before executing some stuff from rabbitmq:3.6.14 image because when I run the container I can't see any logs from the base image. That's why it can't find docker-entrypoint.sh because it hasn't been copied at that point